# Getting 404 errors for edit/delete on newly added Codeigniter pages

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to code igniter.  I followed [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/codeigniter/working_with_database.html) step by step.  When accessing my page in xamp, it is displayed properly. But when clicking edit or delete links, I get an 404 errorodeigniter project error.

I did the page linking on my database similar to other example pages, which are working perfectly.

This is the specific error I get for all the new pages I create:

http://localhost/hpc/admin/product/add_materials
404 Page Not Found

The page you requested was not found.

Comment: http://localhost/hpc/admin/index.php/product/add_materials try with this

Comment: did you add route for that ?

Comment: no i did not i just created the page and linked it from my database in the menu table

Comment: no i did not add route for it i just created the page and did the linking fro my database on the menu table

Comment: please help me am stuck here

Comment: how do i add route for the page?

Comment: Cleaned up punctuation and capitalization

Comment: the tutorial link you gave above is broken

Comment: when i try to route the page its shows me error loading  add_materials on my browser please what should i do?